# TypeError: nft.mint is not a function

Tags: solidity, nft, ethers.js, react, ipfs

I am trying to mint an NFT using ether.js, ipfs but got following error while minting.
[image]

Code calling mint function is as following
[image]

and nft is
[image]

Can someone help me understand root cause of this?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be `nftObject.mint(uri)` and `nftObject.tokenCount()` :)

Comment: It does not matter. Reason : NftObject is passed to nft using setState hook.